# How can I set password restrictions in my domain?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Most of the users on my Active Directory use the same password.  How can I restrict them of this? Can I use a GPO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first questions would be:

1. How do you know what passwords your users are using?
2. Why are they using the same one?

If this is some simple dictionary word password, I suggest just expiring the users' passwords and upping the complexity requirements to force a change.

Comment: How do I implement the complexity change? I think there password passes the complexity test.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to stop different users using the same password. The best you can do is force each user's password to expire to get them to change it.